# How to get the next HTML element of a given element using cheerio (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

I have the following HTML code:

```
<p id="calibre_link-1" class="calibre_15">
  <a href="#calibre_link-6">
    <span class="calibre6"><span class="calibre_6"><span class="underline">
       1 Doxologia
    </span></span></span>
  </a>
</p>

<p class="calibre_7"><span class="calibre_1">Justo é o Senhor
em seus santos caminhos,</span></p>
  ....
<p class="calibre_16"><span class="calibre_1">Em verdade.
Aleluia! Aleluia!</span></p>

<blockquote class="calibre_17">
  <span class="calibre3"><span class="calibre_1">(Sl 145.17,18
  — A. Cunha)</span></span>
</blockquote>
```

And i wish to get all the subsequent text inside 'p' tags until the blockquotes, but my JS code dont work.

```
$('span[class="calibre_6"]').each(
  (i, el) => {
    var title = $(el).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').replace(/ +(?= )/g, '');    

    console.log( $(el.target).find('p').text() );

    hymns[i]["title"] = title;      
  });
```

Comment: `hymns` is not defined. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/n9a7qhks/).

Comment: Sorry, but i forgot to mention that this is just a part of the entire code, i didn't paste the variable declarations.

Comment: If you wish to select all `p` tags, don't select `'span[class="calibre_6"]'`. Select `'p'`!. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/n9a7qhks/1/) out.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `nextUntil` to collect the elements between the two tags and `addBack` to keep the first selected element.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<your HTML>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const text = $("#calibre_link-1")
  .first()
  .nextUntil("blockquote")
  .addBack()
  .get()
  .map(e => $(e).text().trim());
console.log(text);
```

Output:

```js
[
  '1 Doxologia',
  'Justo é o Senhor\nem seus santos caminhos,',
  'Em verdade.\nAleluia! Aleluia!'
]
```

See also:

- [jQuery/cheerio get combined HTML between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60344261/jquery-cheerio-get-combined-html-between-tags/74972202#74972202)
- [Find html text between two tags using jquery or cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72054568/find-html-text-between-two-tags-using-jquery-or-cheerio/74972499#74972499)
- [Web scraping between two tags, using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974070/web-scraping-between-two-tags-using-cheerio/74972539#74972539)