# Web scraping between two tags, using cheerio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping, cheerio

Good evening everyone,

I study cheerio and try to parse the data from the site. Its structure is below, I'll go straight to body:

```
<body>
<form>
<div class="a">
<h3>Text A</h3>
<h4> Sub-Text A</h4>
<div class="Sub-Class A"> some text </div>
<h4> Sub-Text B</h4>
<div class="Sub-Class B"> some text </div>
<h4> Sub-Text C</h4>
<div class="Sub-Class C"> some text </div>

<h3>Text B</h3>
...
...

<h3>Text C</h3>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

The task is to parse the data into the array from h3 to the next h3 (i.e., h3, all h4 and div following it, but to the next h3). I started writing a function, but I ran into the problem described above. How to let the function understand that I need to write everything down after h3 in one element of array, but before the next h3?

The code that I have at the moment:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const nightmare = Nightmare({show: true})
nightmare  
    .goto(url)
    .wait('body')
    .evaluate(()=> document.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
    .end()
    .then(response =>{
        console.log(getData(response));
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });

let getData = html => {
    data = [];
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('form div.a').each((i, elem)=>{
        data.push({

        });
    });
    return data;
}
```

Comment: How is the current result different from what you want?

Comment: What are you talking about? I don't have it yet. As the result, I want to have an array, which contains elements, consist of h3, all h4 and divs.
Smth like:
Array= [ {h3, h4, div, h4, div}, ... {h3, h4, div, h4, div]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just follow the "next()" element until you find a h3:

```
let texts = $('h3').map((i, el) => {
  let text = ""
  el = $(el)
  while(el = el.next()){
    if(el.length === 0 || el.prop('tagName') === 'H3') break
    text += el.text() + "\n"
  }
  return text
}).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see at least a couple of approaches, depending on what you want.

Perhaps you want to select an `<h3>`, say, the first, and traverse to the `<h3>` after it, collecting all of the elements and ignoring all other `<h3>` tags:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const text = $("h3")
  .first()
  .nextUntil("h3")
  .map((i, e) => $(e).text())
  .toArray();
console.log(text);
```

This gives:

```js
[
  ' Sub-Text A',
  ' some text ',
  ' Sub-Text B',
  ' some text ',
  ' Sub-Text C',
  ' some text '
]
```

These can be joined easily, if you wish.

Another interpretation is that you want to chunk all of the `<h2>` segments into separate subarrays:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<body>
<form>
<div class="a">
<h3>Text A</h3>
<h4> Sub-Text A</h4>
<div class="Sub-Class A"> some text </div>
<h4> Sub-Text B</h4>
<div class="Sub-Class B"> some text </div>
<h4> Sub-Text C</h4>
<div class="Sub-Class C"> some text </div>

<h3>Text B</h3>
<h4> B STUFF</h4>
<div class="Sub-Class D"> B STUFF </div>

<h3>Text C</h3>
<div>C STUFF</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const groups = [...$("h3")]
  .map(e => [...$(e).nextUntil("h3")].map(e => $(e).text()));
console.log(groups);
```

This gives

```js
[
  [
    ' Sub-Text A',
    ' some text ',
    ' Sub-Text B',
    ' some text ',
    ' Sub-Text C',
    ' some text '
  ],
  [ ' B STUFF', ' B STUFF ' ],
  [ 'C STUFF' ]
]
```

See also:

- [jQuery/cheerio get combined HTML between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60344261/jquery-cheerio-get-combined-html-between-tags/74972202#)
- [Find html text between two tags using jquery or cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72054568/find-html-text-between-two-tags-using-jquery-or-cheerio/74972499#74972499)