# jQuery/cheerio get combined HTML between tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I want to take apart some HTML code with cheerio in my Node.js and i need to get the combined HTML of all tags between two `<hr>` tags.

[image: example]

I want the combined HTML of all the Tags in the red circle. How could i achieve that?

Comment: First step, take a look at https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil

Comment: @Taplar yeah I’ve tried that, but I had problems with getting multiple elements. If I do nextUntil(‘hr’) and then call .html() on it, I just get the HTML of the first element. If I do .each() or .map() I can’t get the HTML of the elements in the loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the HTML content in between 2 `<hr class="cl-right">` without any library, only using common string operation.
Maybe this workaround will help you:

```
let content = '<!-- Plugin inserted: [begin] -->'
content+= '<div class="news-single-item">'
content+= '<div style="float: right;"></div>'
content+= '<a href="nachrichten/einzelansicht/article/im-dienst.html" title="Neue Schulsanitate im Dienst">Neue Schulsanitater im Dienst</a>'
content+= '<div class="news-single-rightbox"></div>'
content+= '<h1>Exkursion der Literaturkurse</h1>'
content+= '<hr class="cl-right">'
content+= '<div class="news-single-img"></div>'
content+= '<p></p>'
content+= '<p></p>'
content+= '<p>(Sophie Daubenspeck fOr die Literaturk </p>'
content+= '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
content+= '<p>&nbsp;</p>'
content+= '<hr class="cl-right">'
content+= '<div class="news-single-backlink"></div>'
content+= '</div>'
content+= '<!-- Plugin inserted: [end] -->'
content+= '</div>'

const getContentInside = html => {
    return html.split('<hr class="cl-right">')[1]
}
console.log(getContentInside(content))
```

Then if you request the content from an URL:

```
const url = 'http://www.example.com/your.desired.url.here'
const request = require ('request-promise')

const getContentInside = html => {
    return html.split('<hr class="cl-right">')[1]
}

const startParse = async url => {
    const html = await request(url)
    const contentHR = getContentInside(html)
    console.log(contentHR)
}

startParse(url)
```

Comment: Don't use string manipulation on HTML tags, even if it's not regex. If the markup changes by even a single whitespace or class, for example, `<hr class="cl-right foobar">`, this breaks unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches. One way is with [`nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/):

```js
const html = `
<p>some stuff</p>
<hr class="cl-right">
<div class="news-single-img">
  want
</div>
<p>all</p>
<p>of</p>
<p>this</p>
<hr class="cl-right">
<p>some more stuff</p>
`;
const text = $(html, "hr.cl-right")
  .nextUntil("hr.cl-right")
  .map((i, e) => $(e).text().trim())
  .get()
  .slice(0, -1);
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want the HTML as a string, you can use [an outerHTML strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744244/6243352) like:

```js
const html = `
<p>some stuff</p>
<hr class="cl-right">
<div class="news-single-img">
  want
</div>
<p>all</p>
<p>of</p>
<p>this</p>
<hr class="cl-right">
<p>some more stuff</p>
`;
const result = $(html, "hr.cl-right")
  .nextUntil("hr.cl-right")
  .slice(0, -1)
  .wrapAll("<div>")
  .parent()
  .html();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For cheerio, try:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<p>some stuff</p>
<hr class="cl-right">
<div class="news-single-img">
  want
</div>
<p>all</p>
<p>of</p>
<p>this</p>
<hr class="cl-right">
<p>some more stuff</p>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html)
const text = $("hr.cl-right")
  .first()
  .nextUntil("hr.cl-right")
  .map((i, e) => $(e).text().trim())
  .get();
console.log(text);
```

For HTML:

```js
const html = `
<p>some stuff</p>
<hr class="cl-right">
<div class="news-single-img">
  want
</div>
<p>all</p>
<p>of</p>
<p>this</p>
<hr class="cl-right">
<p>some more stuff</p>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const htmlOut = $.html($("hr.cl-right").first().nextUntil("hr.cl-right"));
console.log(htmlOut);
```

See also:

- [Web scraping between two tags, using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974070/web-scraping-between-two-tags-using-cheerio/74972539#74972539)
- [Find html text between two tags using jquery or cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72054568/find-html-text-between-two-tags-using-jquery-or-cheerio/74972499#74972499)