# Find html text between two tags using jquery or cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I thought that this would be rather straightforward but nothing really much work. I am writing this using cheerio in node js.
Basically, I have the following HTML

```
<h2 id="understanding-adc">
<a class="anchor" href="#understanding-adc" aria-hidden="true"><span class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Understanding ADC</h2>

<p>test</p>

<ol>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>Optimization</li>
</ol>

<h2 id="data-switching">
<a class="anchor" href="#data-switching" aria-hidden="true"><span class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Data switching</h2>

<p>test test.</p>
```

So the scenario will be like this . If I pass the a h2 tag id lets say "#understanding-adc" I need to get the content between "#understanding-adc" and the next h2 tag "#data-switching". Here I know which h2 tag I needs to pass to the function, but not the second one.

The result I'm looking for is this:

```
<h2 id="understanding-adc">
    <a class="anchor" href="#understanding-adc" aria-hidden="true"><span class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Understanding ADC</h2>
    
    <p>test</p>
    
    <ol>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>Optimization</li>
    </ol>
```

Please help me

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/ should help.

Comment: This helped me http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NhYX4/

Comment: @MeeraSebastian feel freet to [add a self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you solved the problem so you can help future visitors with the same issue as you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to first select the starting `<h2>`, then use `nextUntil()` to reach the end `<h2>`, call `addBack()` to put the first `h2` element back into the result, then use `$.html()` to grab the outer HTML:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<h2 id="understanding-adc">
<a class="anchor" href="#understanding-adc" aria-hidden="true"><span class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Understanding ADC</h2>

<p>test</p>

<ol>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>Optimization</li>
</ol>

<h2 id="data-switching">
<a class="anchor" href="#data-switching" aria-hidden="true"><span class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Data switching</h2>

<p>test test.</p>
`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const htmlOut = $.html($("#understanding-adc").first().nextUntil("h2").addBack());
console.log(htmlOut);
```

See also:

- [Web scraping between two tags, using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974070/web-scraping-between-two-tags-using-cheerio/74972539#74972539)
- [jQuery/cheerio get combined HTML between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60344261/jquery-cheerio-get-combined-html-between-tags/74972202#)